# Android Java AsyncTask work externally

Tags: java, c#, android, android-asynctask, return

I'm new in Java/Android and I come from c#. I've been taking a look into it and testing I found that when I execute an AsyncTask the mainthread keeps executing while the external task is doing it's work. I even found that I can only set the asynctask that execute an external task from the MainActivity.

My problem is that I want to execute an external class that when finished brings back the results(just like c#) to the maintask without setting the async class in the MainActivity.

So.. in code should be something like:

## MainActivity.java

```
public onClickButton(View view) {
    String result = SecondaryClass.DoAsyncTask();
}
```

## SecondaryClass.java

```
private class DoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Integer, Integer> 
{
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Long... params) {
        String longString = ThirdAPIClass.GiveMeSomeCode(); //Or work here
        return lognString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        return result; //Somehow(?)
    }
}
```

Any idea if there is something similar in Java/Android(?)

PD: I use AsyncTask as an example, I don't know if there is another instruction that do the same or something like that.

Comment: You could have `public static String result;`, and in `onPostExecute` modify it: `MainActivity.result = result;`, not sure of safe it would be though in a big app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Class Singnature:

First Note is that if your result is a String then you need to change your extend clause to:

```
class DoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Integer, String>
```

### Communicating with calling activity:

The `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` signature is `void` and it doesn't return data. The most common practices are:

1. To have this class as an inner class inside your activity, and `onPostExecute` you can call a method inside that activity.
2. Add a constuctor to you asyncTask class and pass the activity to it and then call the method using that instance of activity.

First Approach:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        someMethodInMainActivity(result);
    }
```

Second Approach:

```
public class DoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Integer, String> 
{
     YouActivityName  _activity;
     public DoAsyncTask(YouActivityName activity)
     {
        _activity = activity;
     }

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(Long... params) {
        String longString = ThirdAPIClass.GiveMeSomeCode(); //Or work here
        return lognString;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(_activity != null) {
          _activity.someMethodInMainActivity(result);
        }
     }
}
```

Then you create your AsynTask using :

```
new DoAsyncTask(this);
```

Comment: So with the second one I'll execute another fucnction in the main activity, right?

Comment: @PaulD With the second one you pass an instance of your activity to the AsyncTask class using the constructor. Then when the async work is done, you use that instance to execute a public method inside your activity and pass to that method the `result` of your async method.